# Android - How to retrieve and display Image from sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

so for my android application i can insert an image to sqlite as a string. But im not sure exactly how i can retrieve this image from the database and convert it to a Image from string and display it in my app. Stuck for weeks, help appreciated! :(

Button Click saves image to sqlite

```
  upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Student student = new Student(profadmin.getText().toString());
            student.setImageUri(ImageUri);
            stud.updateImage(student);
            Toast passes = Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Profile Picture has been updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            passes.show();

        }
    });
```

Database Handler:

```
public int updateImage(Student student) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(STUDENT_IMAGEURI, student.getImageUri().toString());


    int rowsAffected = db.update(STUDENT_TABLE, values, STUDENT_ADMINNO + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(student.getAdminNo())});
    db.close();

    return rowsAffected;
}
```

Edit: Uploaded the image by clicking the empty ImageView (profileIV) , opening the android emulator gallery, choose image and then image will be displayed on the app. Then i click the 'Upload' button and it sends it to the database and uploads

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode,int resCode,Intent data){

    if(resCode==RESULT_OK){
        if(reqCode==1){
            ImageUri = data.getData();
            profileIV.setImageURI(data.getData());
        }


    }
```

Comment: Is there a folder which saves all images or can you "upload" a random picture?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is storing your pictures in your `drawable` folder.

Then you will just have to store the name in your database and retrieve the corresponding image thanks to this one. It will also allow you to avoid a  heavy DB file.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to store image into database? it's not a good choice.
If you have to store image into database, you can encode you image with Base64,and store the result string into database. so you can decode the string to image. But this way will cause problems with large images.

I suggest you to store images with disk cache.